# emscriptem - how to read a C-array from JavaScript (Chrome/Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, webassembly

Here's my C code:

```
// helloworld.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE getIntArray(){
    static int numbers[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
    return numbers;
}
```

Here's some of my JS:

```
// helloworld.html
let result = Module.ccall('getIntArray', // name of C function
  'Uint8Array', // return type
  [null], // argument types
  [null]); // arguments

let array = new Uint8Array(result,5);

console.log(result); // prints 1024
console.log(array); // prints Uint8Array(1024) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, … ]
```

All of this compiles and runs fine. The above code works fine for primitive values, but fails with the array pointer, and the JS typed array I get back is all zeros. I have seen some other solutions in the documentation, but they don't seem to work for me either.

Comment: Your function returns a pointer which is an integer instead of an array. In fact there is no array types in C. You will need to access the heap to [get the wanted section out of the memory](https://becominghuman.ai/passing-and-returning-webassembly-array-parameters-a0f572c65d97). To make things easier, there is an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-arrays) that can be used to deal with arrays.

Comment: Changed my C function to this, same result: `int8_t* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE getIntArray(){
 static int8_t numbers[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}; 
 return &numbers[0];
}`

Comment: Well your new code is equivalent to your previous code snippet, so nothing will change. (`&numbers[0]` is equivalent to `&*(numbers + 0)`) But the point is, your function returns an address, not an array.

Comment: OK - so I think the problem is on the JavaScript side - I'll take a look at the npm module you linked to - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `getIntArray` function is going to return an integer which is the location of the array in the WebAssembly modules linear memory. In order to use this, you will need a reference to the module's linear memory.

One option is to create the linear memory on the JavaScript side:

```
const imports = {
    env: {
      memoryBase: 0,
      tableBase: 0,
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 512
      }),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 0,
        element: 'anyfunc'
      })
    }
  };

  const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, imports);
```

You can then use the returned result, which will be an integer, as an offset into linear memory:

```
 const result = Module.ccall('getIntArray', // name of C function
  'Uint8Array', // return type
  [null], // argument types
  [null]); // arguments

  const data = new Uint8Array(imports.env.memory.buffer, result, 5);
```

Comment: That last line `const data = new Uint8Array(imports.env.memory.buffer, result, 5);` did it - thanks so much!

Comment: This is a great explanation!  Do you know where/if this is documented?